# How do I import data from another sheet and then filter it based on 2 different variables?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been working on how I budget and keep track of my finances. In the process, I put together [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GGgFCfMtB5ROkTmpx4Fn4nZZbBIvBa4vpOwqswH5E0/edit?usp=sharing) which I am happy to share a dummy version of (includes dummy data).

I use a Google Form to input new entries which are recorded in the 'Log' page.

From here, I use a few SUMIFS to pull in the totals of any given income/expense category based on the category name (referenced in the cell adjacent), the month (B3), and the year (C3).

What I now want to do is add a table (currently in columns O:Q) that calls in itemised log records based on the category selected (O2) and the month and the year. On the reference sheet these are cells (B3) and (C3) respectively and in the log, these are columns (F) and (G).

I've gotten as far as using an INDEX / SMALL array formula combination to pull in all spending as per the category selected in (O2), but what I cannot seem to figure out is how to then restrict results to only those that also match the month and year. I've tried using a MATCH formula but am unsure how to append this within the current formula string, if it is even possible?

Once working, this would (for example) mean that only rows 4 and 5 in columns O, P, and Q would be populated as these are the records for the selected month, June 2016.

Is what I want to do possible through a more complex formula? Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance.

Link to my Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GGgFCfMtB5ROkTmpx4Fn4nZZbBIvBa4vpOwqswH5E0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you make it possible to copy the sheet please? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?visit_id=1-636101739039148485-4172065213&p=prevent_download&rd=2

Comment: * Google sheet now taken offline. Thankyou to opowell for a perfect solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

1. Delete everything in O4:Q14
2. In cell O4, write: =FILTER(Log!H2:H, Log!B2:B=O$2, Log!G2:G=C$3, Log!F2:F=B$3)
3. In cell P4, write: =FILTER(Log!E2:E, Log!B2:B=O$2, Log!G2:G=C$3, Log!F2:F=B$3)
4. In cell Q4, write: =FILTER(Log!D2:D, Log!B2:B=O$2, Log!G2:G=C$3, Log!F2:F=B$3)

(By the way, you can generate columns F, G and maybe E from column A in the Logs sheet. For example, just remove the data that is already in column G and in G2 write: =ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(A2:A))

Link to spreadsheet with fixes:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIplXRa28L7FdmqI91RbjApO3g-GU5uk6rTQLqi7vFw/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you so much! And to think I spent so long working out that complex ARRAY/INDEX/SMALL formula and filter was all I needed all along.

Thanks also for the tips on the E/F/G columns for the Log sheet. I might leave these in as custom fields since I'm not always quick enough to log things on the date/month that I want them recorded for, but this is good to know.

Comment: No worries, it's always more obvious in hindsight.